# Turn off all connectivity except GPS

Tags: iphone

I am leaving on a camping trip tomorrow. I have an iPhone 6 from my employer. I would like to use the phone for GPS (vis Google Maps) over the weekend, but do not want to receive a single notification for a phone call, text message, calendar invite or email (I am using the Good app). Is there any way to put my phone on airplane mode but keep GPS on? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to completely disable all cellular abilities (calls, texting, data) you could simply take out the SIM.  True GPS still works fine, as that does not use the cellular network.

Answer (score 2):

You can go to Settings and turn Cellular Data off (turn WiFi off for good measure also in case you wander past a WiFi network). Also turn on Do Not Disturb mode. You still use the cell radio to locate your position, unlike in Airplane Mode.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Will that also prevent text messages and phone calls?

Comment: I just tried this and was able to successfully place a call to the iPhone. I had also turned off "Enable LTE" for good measure. Is there anything else I should be doing?

Comment: Sorry, I have an iPad and forgot that turning off cellular data doesn't turn off the whole voice thing. Modifying my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I played around a bit and found that putting the phone in Do Not Disturb mode in conjunction with disabling notifications for the apps I want to avoid (Good, Facebook, etc.) seemed to work.